# I'm trying to use a regular expression to retrieve text from RichTextBox

Tags: c#, regex, search

As the header is implying I'm trying to retrieve a certain line of numbers from a richtextbox and then put it into a separate textbox. I've tried this code below but it doesn't wanna work with me. It's probably way wrong and there's probably easier ways of doing it but I'm quite new to this stuff and I would appreciate all the help I can get in this matter.

I have a textbox called tbPersNr;

A RichTextBox called tbText;

A button which is called btnGet;

```
    string regPattern = @"\\d{6}-\\d{4}";

    int indexOfSearch = 0;

    private void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int startIndex = 0;

        if (tbText.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            startIndex = HittaPersNr(regPattern, startIndex, tbText.Text.Length); 
        }

        if (startIndex > 0)
        {
            this.tbPersNr.Text = regPattern.ToString();
        }
    }

    public int HittaPersNr(string txtToSearch, int searchStart, int searchEnd)
    {
        // Setting default value to -1.
        int retVal = -1;

        // Validating start of the search
        // om indexOfSearch = -1, slutar sökningen
        if (searchStart >= 0 && indexOfSearch >= 0)
        {
            // Validating end of search
            if (searchEnd > searchStart || searchEnd == -1)
            {
                // Searching for results in richtextbox
                indexOfSearch = tbText.Find(regPattern, searchStart, searchEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.None);

                // Validating if search resulted in any finds.
                if (indexOfSearch != -1)
                {
                    // putting index to value in the text.
                    retVal = indexOfSearch;
                }
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

Cheers for all helpful answers,,,and sorry for expressing myself quite clumsy. But I expected I was on the wrong track here and I'm gonna try fix my app with some of the answers. Welbog,,,good detective work there,,,hehehe,,,good that you understood what I was meaning. Thanks all of you who pointed out how to write the Regex in a proper way,,,quite confusing.

Most greatful

Simon

Comment: @Simon - Welcome to StackOverflow. However, there several problems with your question. First - you didn't ask a question. Second - you didn't specify the errors you are getting and the issues you have encountered. Makes it difficult for people to give meaningful answers.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a very helpful diagnosis of the situation. What specifically is this code doing that you don't expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use a regular expression that checks for 6 digits, followed by a `-` and then 4 digits, then you regex is wrong:

```
@"\\d{6}-\\d{4}"
```

You either use a [string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx), or escape your `\` but not both.

Either of these is OK:

```
@"\d{6}-\d{4}"
"\\d{6}-\\d{4}"
```

Additionally, you are trying to use a regular expression in the `Find` method of the `RichTextbox`, which doesn't take a regular expression!

Answer (score 0):

`RichTextBox.Find()` is **not** a RegEx-Function!

Use `Regex.Match(tbText.Text, regPattern)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really want to search for something that contains `\`, I think you might have too many backslashes there. Shouldn't it be this?

```
    string regPattern = @"\d{6}-\d{4}";
```

The `@` in front of your string prevents the backslashes from being interpreted, so they become part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

It *looks like* you intend to match your pattern and then print the result to the textbox named `tbPersNr`. At least that's what I think this code is for:

```
if (tbText.Text.Length > 0)
{
  startIndex = HittaPersNr(regPattern, startIndex, tbText.Text.Length);
}

if (startIndex > 0)
{
  this.tbPersNr.Text = regPattern.ToString();
}
```

But `regPattern` is a string set to `\\d{6}-\\d{4}`. It is not replaced with what the pattern matched, which I believe is what you're expecting (I can't really tell, but I see no reason why you would print a string literal like that). So in addition to the points the other answers bring up, you need to actually retrieve the value you've matched from your rich text box in order to display it.

A call to `Substring` will do the trick, using the `startIndex` you've already found and a length of `11` (which is the length of a string matched by your regular expression).